# Timeout for every socket, possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to create a Timeout for every socket based on specific action? For example, let's say, user clicks a button, after Onclick on this button I emit to server with timeout value for example 2000, and on server side, I count it down to 0, and every socket wouldn't be allowed to click that button if counter on server side is not equal to 0. The counting itself is not that hard, simple Interval. But on the client side, it's kind of tricky because I don't know how to check if the counter on the server side is 0 without emitting to the server and somehow disable overwriting the variable if the user clicks the button before the counting is over. Any idea?

***Client:***

```js
socket.on("TimeoutResponse", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.emit("Timeout", "10");
```

***Server:***

```js
socket.on('Timeout', function(data) {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    data--;
    socket.emit('TimeoutResponse', data);
    if (data <= "0") {
      clearInterval(interval);
      socket.emit('TimeoutResponse', "Done");
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply disable the button after the user clicks it and once you recieve `'TimeoutResponse', 'Done'` enable it again? This way they can't click it until the countdown is over.

Comment: The button is just an example because it would be hard for me to copy all the stuff her. All I want to archive is when a player is close to a specific monster in the game it will run a function, emit timeout value 100  so other people which come near, won't send the same function and spam it over.